# Android add image to database

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, store

I made a program that when the user presses on the imagebutton he will select an image from the gallery which will be embadded in the imagebutton. now i need to extend the program that when the user presses an add button that image in the imagebutton will be stored in the database together with the description(user inputs text in an edit text e.g. sport)...i already created a class for the database etc...

can anyone help me to add the code of case  'case R.id.button2' that is when the add button is clicked please?

thanks a lot

```
public class NewPortal extends Activity implements OnClickListener, android.view.View.OnClickListener

{
 public static final int REQUEST_CODE =1;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 setContentView(R.layout.portallayout);
 ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

 public void onClick(View v) {

  Toast pieceToast=null;

  switch (v.getId()) {

  case R.id.imageButton2:
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setType("image/*");
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
   startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
   break;

   case R.id.button2:
  break;
  }
 }

 @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }



 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RESULT_CANCELED) return;

    ParcelFileDescriptor fd;
    try {
        fd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd.getFileDescriptor());
     ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    imgButton.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to store the image in the database you want to store the image in either your internal or external memory and then store the `Uri` of where that image is located in your database

Comment: haw shall i do that please? the image is already stored internally...when i press the add button it should be stored to the database so then i can retrieve it when i want it.